# Why does my pyqt GUI freeze when I start my program?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I've made an server/client application and need to add a GUI to the server side. So far I've been testing and running it through the terminal cmd window. However when I try to implement a pyqt GUI, the GUI window freezes then crashes.

I suspect the problem lies within the server program which creates two threads, where both are infinite "while true" loops, one waiting for input through the cmd window, and the other waiting for connections (sock.accept()).

I thought I could solve this by making the QApplication (gui) instantiate the server program as a QThread, but that does not seem to be working.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I thought it would be quite common for programs to use infinite "while loops" and a GUI on top?

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.server = ServerThread()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.server.main)

class ServerThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.server = None

    def create_workers(self):
        """ Create worker threads (will die when main exits) """
        self.server = Server()
        self.server.register_signal_handler()
        for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_THREADS):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.work, args=(self.server,))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        return

    def work(self, server):
        """ Do the next job in the queue (thread for handling connections, another for sending commands)
        :param server:
        """
        while True:
            x = queue.get()
            if x == 1:
                self.server.create_mcast_socket()
                self.server.create_tcp_socket()
                self.server.bind_tcp_socket()
                self.server.accept_connections()
            if x == 2:
                self.server.start_turtle()
            queue.task_done()
        return

    def create_jobs(self):
        """ Each list item is a new job """
        for x in JOB_NUMBER:
            queue.put(x)
        queue.join()
        return

    def main(self):
        self.create_workers()
        self.create_jobs()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Did you run a trace?  Have you tried logging?

Comment: where is **server.start()** ? and **main** function should be renamed to **run**. Until you do this, It will not create a separate thread.